# Issue with microsoft word url encoding during webdav protocol

Tags: java, ms-word, webdav

We have :

- a webdav server running on Linux (java application)
- a client on Windows 7, using ms-word 2010

The urls to open our files end with the files' names, and are encoded in UTF-8 before to be sent to the UI :

> server.com/path/my_file_name.doc

It works perfectly with file names without special characters but with an ugly url like

> server.com/path/En-tête de lettre + capital 1 050 000 €.doc

, our server does not manage to access to the file.
In the stack trace, we can see that the url received by the server is

> server.com/path/En-tÃªte de lettre + capital 1 050 000 â?¬.doc

, but the error message that ms-word is displaying contains the right url, so I think that the original url is right.

And last but not least : it works when the server is running on a windows platform.

I suppose that ms-word re-encodes the url before transmitting it to the server, but I can't guess how to decode it.

All suggestions are welcome ^^

Comment: getting `â` like that is a sign of unicode mangling. you have unicode in a url and then it gets mangled into some OTHER character set, e.g. iso8859 or win-1252.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of http://milton.io (java webdav server lib) and I've seen an issue where MS clients do incorrect encoding of some url's, and milton has some workarounds for that. What webdav framework/server are you using?

However, **the example given looks more like mangling**, as suggested by Marc B. Your server is probably outputting the propfind response in UTF-8, but windows is interpreting it as win-1252.

So you should look at the response headers and check to see what character encoding is given for the response and check that it matches the actual encoding used in the PROPFIND response.

Note that earlier versions of milton had a problem where they would use the server default encoding but always report UTF-8, so this problem would occur on any server not using UTF-8 as the default character encoding.

Comment: We are using webdav-servlet : http://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav-servlet/ in the version 2.0.1.
I'm going too see at the profind response, thanks.

Comment: OK, you two were right : the url was mangled into windows-1252.
So we decode it now from UTF-8 and re-encode it into windows-1252 before sending it to ms-word, which does not mangle it, this time.

Thus, it works with firefox, which transmits a correctly UTF-8-encoded url (but not with IE, which also mangles the url into windows-1252, in a way where we can't correct it).

Thanks to you.